# Magento Ignore Child Attributes in Layered Navigation

Tags: magento, attributes, layered

I have some bundled products that have attributes associated with them. The child products also have the same attributes associated with them, however they are sometimes different. My issue is that with layered navigation, it is looking at both the bundled product and all the child products' attributes. I was wondering if there was any way to edit the layered navigation to ignore child products for bundled products. Thanks!

For some more information:
I am setting up a store for HVAC equipment. I have an attribute called Nominal Capacity. The air condenser unit might be 2 tons, the coil might be 1.5 to 2 tons. When I put them together in a bundle product, I set the Nominal Capacity attribute for the bundled product to 2 tons, however the layered navigation still shows 1.5 to 2 ton and 2 ton when I need it to only show 2 tons.

Comment: Please, provide more information: code samples, screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From magento's point of view you have 3 products (following exapmle) air condenser(1), coil(2), bundle of 1 and 2(3). If you only want the bundled products info to appear then in 'manage products' select the air condenser or coil. Once in the 'edit product' form find the field for 'visibility' and change this value to 'Not Visible individually'.

This will fix your layered navigation behavior however it will also make it impossible to purchase a individual element of your bundle. If you want a customer to be able to purchase your bundle or single elements of a bundle then the current layered navigation behavior is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however I don't think that I will be able to go this route as I need to have my customers buy the products individually as well.

Comment: alright, I guess I am confused by why you want to remove these attributes from the layered navigation? if you remove the values from layered navigation how would a customer find the individual products?

Comment: I have separate categories for the individual items (ie: category for air condensers, category for coils, etc) and then I have one category for the complete air conditioner system that shows only bundled products and does not include any individual item. I am sorry that I didn't make that more clear in my initial post.

Comment: you might be able to adapt this to suit your needs http://www.manadev.com/blog/hiding-or-showing-filters-in-categories/ . I have not tested this.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I think this gets me in the right direction.